# Multiple array null value?

Tags: foreach, laravel-5.1

I try to insert mutiple arrays per job_id when i try this my array values out put as null value this is my store function

`$input` output :

```
array:7 [▼ 
     "date" => "2016-01-10",
     "job_id" => "2",
     "charge" => array:2 [▼ 
           0 => "ch1",
           1 => "ch2" 
     ],
     "category" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "se1",
          1 => "se2" 
     ],
     "amount" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "100"
          1 => "200" 
     ]
 ]
```

Full Code :

```
$input = Input::all();

$charge = Input::get('charge');
$date = Input::get('date');
$job = Input::get('job_id');
$amount = Input::get('amount');
$cat = Input::get('category');
$id = \Auth::id();

$data = array();

foreach ($charge as $key=>$value ){
    $data[] = [
          'date' => $date,
          'charge'=>$key['charge'],
          'job_id'=>$job,
          'user_id'=>$id,
          'amount'=>$key['amount'],
          'category'=>$key['category'],
    ];
}

dd($data);
```

When i try to get out put i will get this out put

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "date" => "2016-01-10"
    "charge" => null
    "job_id" => "2"
    "user_id" => 1
    "amount" => null
    "category" => null
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "date" => "2016-01-10"
    "charge" => null
    "job_id" => "2"
    "user_id" => 1
    "amount" => null
    "category" => null
  ]
]
```

What i want is i want insert data to my database any one suggest me good idea ?

Answer for this question from Laracast [Check this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-insert-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final output looks correct, try to use the following code to insert the `$data` to your DB :

```
Model::insert($data); // Eloquent
DB::table('table')->insert($data); // Query Builder
```

You should construct your array using `$inputs['amount'][$key]` for amount value and `$inputs['category'][$key]` for category, like following :

```
foreach ($charge as $key=>$value ){
    $data[] = [
          'date' => $date,
          'charge'=>$value,
          'job_id'=>$job,
          'user_id'=>$id,
          'amount'=>$inputs['amount'][$key],
          'category'=>$inputs['amount'][$key],
    ];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: :) ya but im trying get out put so i used dd() to check my ouput  so im getting **null**

Comment: Okay try to do `dd($input)` and add the output to the OP.

Comment: yes this is output `array:7 [▼

  "date" => "2016-01-10"
  "job_id" => "2"
  "charge" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "ch1"
    1 => "ch2"
  ]
  "category" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "se1"
    1 => "se2"
  ]
  "amount" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "100"
    1 => "200"
  ]

]`

Comment: when i try this foreach loop `foreach ($charge as $key ){
            $data[] = [
                'date' => $date,
                'charge'=>$key,
                'job_id'=>$job,
                'user_id'=>$id,
                'amount'=>$amount,
                'category'=>$cat,
        ];
        }` charges i can insert but amount and category first value insert all the charges

Comment: please edit your answer  'charge'=>$key['charge'], as 'charge'=>$value its working perfect edit yours plz

Comment: :) Done, check it now.

Comment: bro if you know laravel document generation (PDF, EXCEL) and filtering in table by id or name suggest me some link plz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100288/discussion-between-prudential-developer-and-zakaria-acharki).